# Best implementation of web service with a huge list lookup

Tags: php, mysql, list, search, lookup

I am planning to offer a simple phrase lookup web service. the number of phrases is around 3-5 million entries, and each entry is less than 50 characters. The service is quite simple, if a phrase given by the user is in the list return true and else return false. So on the server side, should I just simply put the entries in mysql database and query it whenever user phrase comes in? Is there any other implementation that is more efficient? i.e. faster, less memory, more scaleable in terms of query volume, etc. Or should load it in memory?

Any feedback, ideas, opinions would be appreciated!

Comment: What server-side language are you using?  PHP, Java, etc...

Comment: Are you going to search only for complete matches, or for something more flexible?  In other words, if I'm a user, and I want to search for the phrase "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", will you let me type in just "Lorem ipsum" and do a wildcard match, or will you require me to type in the whole thing?

Comment: @Catcall, For now, I am just considering exact match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL should handle 5 million entries without any trouble.

If I were you, I'd build the database and test it locally with 5 million and with 50 million rows of pseudorandom data.

If you're able to simulate a lot of concurrent connections, then do that.  If not, just roll it out to, say, 100 interested users.

Keep records.  Use analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/). Easy to use and fast.

Comment: Thanks, Franz. Please see my question to @Cornel below. Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how many concurrent users you'll have.

If you have lots of requests/second, keep the data into memory (looks like you need lots of it), memcached for example.
Else, use a database.

Or use both: if the data is not the cache (memcached), load from the database and keep it the memory for future needs.

Comment: Thanks, Cornel. What's the typical size of memcached? I am new to it and their website says it is good to keep a small chunk of name value pairs. I am not sure what "small" means here and if it would be of much help in my case.

Comment: It really depends on how much data you're going to store in it. Check this [tutorial](http://papermashup.com/using-memcache-with-php/). But perhaps a SQL database would do. Run some tests.

Comment: Also, memcached is good for name-value pairs, but my case is a linear array of phrases.